# How to create n number of arrays based on user input in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I want to prompt the user to enter a number, and then have the computer create that many arrays.

For example if the user entered the number `5`, I would would want `5 integer arrays` called `array1[64], array2[64], array3[64], array4[64], and array5[64]` to be created.

Comment: Is there an upperbound on the user entry. You can achieve some dynamism via malloc but as a whole it wouldn't work like you want

Comment: Even if you could get that to work how would you go about getting the array you desired? ie arrayN? Other languages can handle this sort of case, but C isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array of pointers

Like following :-

```
int n,i;

//enter n

int **array = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*64);

 /* Do Stuffs*/


/* Free Memory */  
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  free(array[i]);

free(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you say, "I want N variables of the same type named `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ..., `varN`", what you really want is an array; in this case, you want an array of arrays.

Assuming that you know the second dimension at compile time (i.e., it's *always* going to be an Nx64-element array of `int`), then this is easy:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
size_t numArrs = 0;

// get numArrs from user

int (*arrs)[64] = malloc( sizeof *arrs * numArrs );
```

Presto - you've allocated an Nx64 array of `int` that you can access like any normal 2D array:

```
arrs[i][j] = some_value();
```

`arrs[0]` is your first 64-element array of `int`, `arrs[1]` is your second 64-element array of `int`, etc.